# Bash: can I set Ctrl-Backspace to delete the word backward?

Tags: bash

When in shell (bash) - I want to have Ctrl-Backspace  binded to "delete word backward". Is it possible?

**Edit**:

I'm using `konsole` - terminal at KDE.

Comment: The question is straight forward, no complains about that. I just want to comment that it is often worth a lot to facilitate "standard" key bindings that already exist in many applications, instead of customizing away for no real gain and the certainty of never seeing the behaviour on foreign systems. `Ctrl+w` is what you should get accustomed to, imho.

Comment: @ Daniel Andersson: or alternatively - You can develop a way to [transfer](https://github.com/bk322/bk-goodies/blob/master/bk-sysadmins-kde.py) Your settings to the foreign machine.

Comment: Sharing dotfiles is a solved problem, but it doesn't help much on other than more or less local computers where you have quite open privileges. If you are on a foreign system you most likely don't have the freedom to reconfigure things like that (at least not without getting bashed by colleauges who also use the same machine :-) ). Also, every new application will need special treatment.

Comment: I've got the inverse problem, I'm used to `Ctrl-w` as "delete previous word" in the console, and do it by instinct even in Eclipse or Chrome where it means close tab/close current file. Quite annoying.

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome SShInATab. How do I do ctrl-W without ctrl-W? :)

Comment: ["Up until very recently, gnome-terminal emitted the same code on Backspace and Ctrl+Backspace"](https://askubuntu.com/a/702256/196639)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why not just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> that are already mapped in most terminals. Not sure about Console. Xmodmap (man xmodmap) may be used to remap other custom keys as well. (Paradoxically, xmodmap can't remap Backspace very well because the terminal overrides the mappings, but it works well with most keys...).

Comment: Because I used to Ctrl-Backspace in my Emacs. I knew about Ctrl-w. Alt-Backspace is new to me (+1).

Comment: Good point, @hellork. You could intercept the control+backspace at the X server (via xmodmap) and map it to some unused character (such as alt-backspace).

Comment: The annoying thing about this is that ctrl+backspace is a really common mapping for "delete word backwards" in most GUI apps on most major operating systems. Likewise, Ctrl+W is wide-spread for "close window". Alt+w is rarely used for anything in GUIs, that I can think of. Standardisation would be great. I wonder what would be the bigger disruption, changing terminals, or changing GUIs?

Comment: @naught, Control-W is already the default word-erase key on unix terminals. Yeah it conflicts with the Windows/GUI convention, but in fact it came first--by many years. Blame Microsoft!

Comment: @alexis The Neanderthals also came first by many years. Should we blame ourselves?

Answer (score 25):

Just edit your `~/.inputrc` (you might need to create one or copy the one in `/etc/inputrc` there) so that it contains:

```
# Ctrl-Delete: delete next word
"\e[3;5~": shell-kill-word

# Ctrl-Backspace
"\C-H": shell-backward-kill-word
```

This will map also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the word next to the cursor.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: C-H worked for me with unix-word-rubout, for WSL with the standard windows console app.

Answer (score 14):

I found this thread via google, but the answer wasn't what I wanted to hear.
So I played around:

On my terminal, normal backspace sends `^H`, while ctrl+backspace sends `^?`.
So it should simple be a case of rebinding `^?` to delete a word, which by default is available via Ctrl+W.

#### First (unsuccessful try):

```
$ bind -P | grep 'C-w'
unix-word-rubout can be found on "\C-w".
```

So therefore this should work:

```
$ bind '"\C-?":unix-word-rubout'
```

However it does not... anyone able to explain?

#### Second (successful) try:

```
$ bind '"\C-?":"^W"'
```

Where the `^W` is a literal/raw `^W` (press ctrl+V then ctrl+W to make it appear).

Comment: Your first solution worked for me, actually!  Second did not.

Comment: The second try seems to replace backspace itself rather than Ctrl-Backspace?

Comment: C-? didn't work for me, but C-H did with unix-word-rubout (see Treviño's answer). I'm on WSL with the standard windows console app.

Answer (score 10):

There are some good answers here, but I solved it in Konsole with Settings->Edit Current Profile->Keyboard->Edit, then adding a mapping from `Backspace+Control` to `\x17`. (I found the ASCII code for Ctrl-w using `showkey --ascii`.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the thing with `showkey`. Thus I figured out that `ALT+D` for delete word in front of the cursor would correspond to `\x1b\x64`.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. In my case I need to remap the Alt+Backspace and its sequence is  `\x1b\x7f`.

Comment: To show/hide the menu in Konsole, `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`M`.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what bash sees. On regular terminal interaction, bash does not see what key modifiers you pressed, only the resulting character. Backspace is already the same as control-H, for example. Holding down shift or control makes no difference.

HOWEVER, your terminal application (xterm? cmd? Terminal? Putty? Depends on your OS) can see your keypresses, and may have a way to map the control-backspace key combination to something bash can tell apart from backspace.

Comment: I found that my bash doesn't see backspace. But may be it's possible to make it see that.

Comment: @adobe, what do you mean? Type 'stty' at your terminal and then read the manual about it. If ^H is set to be your erase character, you can set it to something else... if you have a good reason.

Comment: There's a good example of how to do this at https://github.com/calj/gtconf/blob/master/zsh/zshrc. Konsole lets you do it. Copy one of the *.keytab files from /usr/share/kde4/apps/konsole/ into ~/.kde/share/apps/konsole and modify it with the suggestions in the link above, deleting the "key Backspace" line and adding: `key Backspace-Shift-Control : "\x7f"` and `key Backspace-Shift+Control : "\E[9;3~"` Also change the title line while you're at it: `keyboard "Xfree4 Modlist"`, for example. You can then add `"\e[9;3~": backward-kill-word"` to ~/.inputrc

Answer (score 4):

In Konsole:

- click `Settings -> Edit current profile`
- click the 'Keyboard' tab -> `[Edit...]`
- click the `[Add]` button and under the `Key Combination` column type `Backspace+Ctrl`.  In the `Output` column type `0x08` (which is conventionally the backspace character)

Now you should be able to map that key to `backward-kill-word` via

```
# ~/.bashrc

bind '"\x08":backward-kill-word'
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for me, in xfce4-terminal at least.

Comment: Try `\x08` as output if `0x08` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
bind '"\C-_":backward-kill-word'
```

Optionally add the following to ~/.inputrc to make it permanent:

```
"\C-_": backward-kill-word
```

Works on bash 4.3.11 in Kubuntu 14.04

Comment: Control-backspace is unlikely to be the same as Control-underscore.

Comment: Out of all the things I tried in this thread, this worked! Using "GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
on bash on windows/WSL

Comment: This works great for me in cygwin, using `GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)`.

Answer (score 2):

To add to most of the answers here, and to explain why most answers have a comment saying "didn't work for me":

Most terminal emulaters/programs will send a different 'character' to represent ctrl+backspace. Some will not send anything different - pressing ctrl + backspace will send the same thing as backspace. That means if you have a different emulator to what the answerer is using, there's a good chance the character is different.

Some answers have mentioned modifying (via settings) what character gets sent. If you don't want to do that, the way to find out which character bash is receiving from the emulator when you press ctrl + backspace is:

1. At the bash input, press ctrl + v (this key combination might change, but this is a very common one). This will pass through the next character without bash intepreting it.
2. press ctrl + backspace
3. the sequence that appears at the prompt is the character sequence sent by the emulator for ctrl + backspace.
4. repeat the process with regular backspace to confirm it is different from ctrl + backspace.
5. If it is the same, you will have to try the method of changing the terminal settings.

Answer (score 1):

On most terminals CTRL+W should already delete a word backwards.  This works with xterm and I guess it works with konsole.
CTRL+W is a standard key binding on text-based program that will work with vim in insert mode, emacs, and every shells.

Comment: I have Ctrl-w binded to "close tab" in Emacs, FireFox, Krusader - so I set it to be a tab-closing combination in Konsole also.

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me:

```
stty werase ^H
```

Comment: This works fine for me on Windows (git bash), Linux and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) with a `Window Filter` to remap `<ctrl>+<backspace>` for your favorite terminal application: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669238/492533